# Connection Issue for Presto with Hive :Read timed out Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, presto

I am using presto 0.89 with cdh5 Hadoop.
For Hive using mysql for metastore.

Here is my Configuration:

hive.properties

```
connector.name=hive-cdh5
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://demo:9083
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

---

Here is config.properties

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8081
datasources=jmx,hive,mysql
#presto-metastore.db.type=h2
#presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://demo.com:8081
```

Error message:

```
presto:test_db> DESCRIBE hive.test_db.tmp_sears_sign_data;
**Query 20150109_122634_00002_p3r9r failed: x.x.x.x: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out**
```

Comment: If you pass --debug when you launch the presto cli, you will get a full stack trace with the error message.

Since this is a metadata query, my guess is the Presto coordinator is having problems connecting to your Hive Metastore.  Can you connect to the Hive Metastore from the coordinator machine?  You can test with something like "telnet demo 9083".

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your query from **presto-cli in --debug mode**. I believe there is some connectivity issue from your host to metastore. To troubleshoot the issue you can try ping to your metastore from the coordinator node to check if that works fine. If that's all fine then second you can check if all your worker nodes are up with `select * from jmx.system.nodes`.